# Run data provider tests in parallel using testng

Tags: java, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver

I've tests with data provider. Following is the sample code:

```
@DataProvider(name = "testData")
public Object[][] testData(){
    return new Object[][]{
        {"John", "San Jose"},
        {"Mike", "Santa Clara"}
    };
}

@Test(dataProvider = "testData")
public void verifyCity(String name, String city){
   System.out.println("Name: " + name + " city: " + city);
}
```

In this code, I've to run each test in parallel. I'm not using `testng.xml` file. How can I achieve parallelism by making changes at test method level itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In order to make a data provider run in a pool of threads, you use the
> annotation *parallel*:

```
@DataProvider(parallel = true)
public Object[][] dp2() {
```

That's actually been taken from this [source](http://beust.com/weblog2/archives/000513.html).

Or have I misunderstood something?